# AwsCustomResource: Howto know when there are no more ResponseFields?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I want to call the SES `verifyDomainDkim` API method via `AwsCustomResource`. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#verifyDomainDkim-property) I know that it returns a response as follows:

```
{
    DkimTokens: [
       "EXAMPLEq76owjnks3lnluwg65scbemvw", 
       "EXAMPLEi3dnsj67hstzaj673klariwx2", 
       "EXAMPLEwfbtcukvimehexktmdtaz6naj"
    ]
}
```

Now I want to use those DkimTokens to create the required CNAME records in Route53. How do I know how many entries the `DkimTokens`array has? I currently have hardcoded looping over 3 records like the following:

```
const verifyDomainDkim = new AwsCustomResource(...);
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      new route53.CnameRecord(this, `ses-dkim-${i}`, {
        zone: props.hostedZone,
        recordName: `${Token.asString(verifyDomainDkim.getResponseFieldReference(`DkimTokens.${i}`))}._domainkey.${domain}`,
        domainName: `${Token.asString(verifyDomainDkim.getResponseFieldReference(`DkimTokens.${i}`))}.dkim.amazonses.com`,
      }).node.addDependency(verifyDomainDkim);
    }
```

However what if at some point there are more than three DKIM tokens? Can I somehow make this dynamic?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? Thanks!